# How to generalize the functions, which acting on a vector of different types?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, c++17, stdvector

I am relatively new to C++ and I can not seem to phrase my question correctly. Since vectorize and map both have meanings which seem different from what I am looking for (so Googling for a solution is difficult).

I have many functions acting on single objects of arbitrary type. I want a general way (i.e. a template or wrapper function) to convert these to functions acting on vectors of the arbitrary number of objects of the same type.

An example:

```
int func1(int a) {return a+1;}
long func2(long a) {return a*10;}

vector<int> func1(vector<int> a_vec)
{
    vector<int> out_vec;
    for (int i = 0; i < a_vec.size(); i++)
        out_vec.push_back(func1(a_vec[i]));
    return out_vec;
}

vector<long> func2(vector<long> a_vec)
{
    vector<long> out_vec;
    for (int i = 0; i < a_vec.size(); i++)
        out_vec.push_back(func2(a_vec[i]));
    return out_vec;
}
```

Templates seem to be necessary but I don't have much experience with them yet and have no idea how to apply them in this case. Any references/suggestions/comments welcome.

(Also please add relevant tags - since I am not sure of the correct term for this I am not sure how to tag it).

Comment: `std::transform` is the function you are looking for almost certainly. Also, since you're not modifying vectors passed into your functions you should pass them by const refferences to avoid unnecessary copies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code does indeed look like a nice fit for some templates.

```
template <typename T, typename TFunc>
std::vector<T> transform(const std::vector<T> &v, TFunc &&func)
{
    std::vector<T> result;
    result.reserve(v.size());
    for (auto &&element : v)
        result.push_back(std::invoke(func, element));
    return result;
}
```

As you might notice the function looks very similar to `std::transform`, which works on iterators instead of vectors. It can be called as:

```
 auto result = transform(v, &func1);
```

Comment: 3) `transform(v, &func1)` can be simplified to `transform(v, func1)`.

Comment: Tnx, I've added `std::forward`. For the `std::transform`, I might agree with you. Unfortunately, I never use it as I find the back_inserters soo confusing. However, it does make sense

Comment: Very nice, thank you. I'm curious about the comment by @Evg, is there an advantage to using `&&`/`invoke`? Is `forward` necessary? I'm not familiar with these.

Comment: If `T` is a simple type like `int`, `result` can be `resize`d, not `reserve`d. If `T` is not that simple, then you'd probably like to generalize your function for different types of elements of input and output vectors to be more generic.

Comment: @Evg `T` is not simple, it is a special type from a separate library

Comment: @Junkhook9000 Most likely going into detail way to much, however, let me explain: `std::invoke` invokes a callable, this is basically because their are several ways of passing something that behaves like a function and has a different way of invoking it. `std::invoke` makes that unified.

Comment: @Evg: Again a habbit, it's my  default in an AAA environment.

Comment: I would NOT recommend `std::forward` here. If `TFunc` actually does have an `operator()(const T&) &&` that steals anything from the `TFunc` object, you'll have a bad time the second time through the loop!

Answer (score 3):

As @paler123 mentioned in the comment, you can use [`std::transform`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) to do the job + a small templated function.

Since your two functions have similarities in the function signature

```
i.e, Type function(Type arg)
```

I chose, typed function pointers as the template function parameters.

```
template<typename Type>
std::vector<Type> func(const std::vector<Type>& a_vec, Type(*func)(Type))
{
    std::vector<Type> out_vec; out_vec.reserve(a_vec.size());
    std::transform(a_vec.begin(), a_vec.end(), std::back_inserter(out_vec), func);
    return out_vec;
}
```

Now in the `main()`, you can either  specify  the type explicitly or leave as it is and let the compiler do the type deduction.

```
auto result = func<int>({ 1,2,3,4 }, func1);
// also can
auto result2 = func({ 1, 2, 3, 4 }, func2);
```

See <kbd>[**sample output here**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/QWwSw3llcGdJmr6e)</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you will need templates since you don't know the types that you'll be using this vectorization function with.

Let's try it:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int func1(int i){ return i + 1; }

template<typename valueT, typename callableT>
std::vector<valueT> vectorize(const std::vector<valueT>& input, callableT funcToCall)
{
    std::vector<valueT> result;
    for (auto& x : input) result.push_back(funcToCall(x));
    return result;
}


int main()
{
    std::vector<int> iVector{2,3,5,7,11,13,17};

    std::vector<int> output = vectorize(iVector, &func1);

    for (const auto& x : output) std::cout << x << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This looks good as does JVApen's answer. I will wait for a while before deciding/accepting, but thank you.